# How can my Bash script see a loop variable inside a command line argument?

Tags: bash, shell

I can't seem to "access" the value of my loop variable when executing a command line argument in a Bash script.  I'd like to be able to write something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for myvar in 1 2 3
do
  $@
done
```

and run the script as `./myscript echo "${myvar}"`.

When I do this, the lines are echoed as empty. I probably don't have a firm grasp one exactly what's being evaluated where.

Is what I want even possible?

Comment: You can use `bash -x myscript` to see how `myvar` is being set (along with a lot of other detail about the execution of your script).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$myvar` is evaluated before the child script is even run, so it can't be evaluated within.

That is, when you invoke your script as:

```
./myscript echo "${myvar}"
```

what is actually being called is:

```
./myscript echo ''
```

presuming that `$myvar` is empty in the enclosing environment.

---

If you wanted to be evil ([and this *is* evil, and will create bugs, and you should not do it](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)), you could use eval:

```
#!/bin/bash
for myvar in 1 2 3; do
  eval "$1"
done
```

...and then call as:

```
./myscript 'echo "${myvar}"'
```

---

Something less awful would be to export a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
export myvar
for myvar in 1 2 3; do
  "$@"
done
```

...but even then, the way you call the script will need to avoid preevaluation. For instance, this will work in conjunction with the above:

```
./myscript bash -c 'echo "$myvar"'
```

...but that basically has you back to eval. On the other hand:

```
./myscript ./otherscript
```

...will do what you want, presuming that `otherscript` refers to `$myvar` somewhere within. (This need not be a shell script, or even a script; it can be an executable or other command, and it will still be able to find `myvar` in the environment).

---

What's the real goal (ie. business purpose) you're trying to achieve? There's probably a way to accomplish it better aligned with best practices.

Comment: Maybe you could use something like `for myvar in 1 2 3; do "$@" "$myvar"; done`

Comment: I started trying roll my own solution to [run a command on several remote machines](http://serverfault.com/questions/2533/linux-running-the-same-command-on-many-machines-at-once) and encountered this issue.

Long term, I'd probably look at one of the tools from that linked question.  For a simple one-off, I thought I could make a simple `for remote in host1 host2 host3; do "$@"; done` sort of thing, plugging `${remote}` in as needed.

I guess the only way to do that (without writing a second script!) is to `eval`?  I might go strait to the heavier-weight tools...

Comment: @Coderer Just pass the hostname as an argument: `"$@" "$remote"

Comment: That doesn't really solve situations like `scp thisFile ${remote}:/foo/bar` -- I mean, I could probably do something with `xargs` I guess, but for personal-use one-offs like this `eval` sounds easier...

Comment: @Coderer eval seriously will cause bugs. Read the linked wiki page.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to polish up my xargs -- I'm thinking that putting `echo ${remote} | xargs -i $@`, then invoking `./myscript ping {}` (for example) might do it?

Comment: @Coderer If `hosts=(host1 host2 host3)`, `printf '%s\0' "${hosts[@]}" | xargs -0 -i "$@"` would be better. xargs without `-print0` is a recipe for suffering; so is echo without quoting its arguments. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls/#echo_.24foo for the latter.